# Why is there Memory Error in recursion function in python?

Tags: python, recursion, memory, memory-management, subsequence

I wrote a code to get all subsequences of a string using recursion in python. Below is the code.

```
def solve(s):

    if (len(s)==0):
        return [""]
    curr = s[0]
    res = s[1:]
    ans = solve(res)
    for i in ans:
        ans.append(curr+i)
    return ans
if __name__=="__main__":
    s=str(input())
    print(solve(s))
```

For input = "ab", the above code is throwing *Memory Error*

I am not sure why is it happening.

On changing the code to following one, it works.

```
def solve(s):

    if (len(s)==0):
        return [""]
    curr = s[0]
    res = s[1:]
    ans = solve(res)
    new = []
    for i in ans:
        new.append(i)
        new.append(curr+i)

    return new

if __name__=="__main__":
    s=str(input())
    print(solve(s))
```

Can someone please explain what is the reason behind *Memory Error* in first code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're iterating through `ans` and adding stuff onto the end of `ans` at the same time. That's an infinite loop (until `ans` gets so long that you run out of memory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
for i in ans:
    ans.append(curr+i)
```

You are iterating through `ans` and adding stuff onto the end of `ans` at the same time. It is an infinite loop: you'll never get to the end of `ans` because you keep making it longer (until you run out of memory).

If you want to add new elements to `ans` which are each of the existing elements preceded by `curr`, you can do that with a list comprehension:

```
ans += [curr + i for i in ans]
```

This way computes all the new elements, and *then* adds them all onto `ans`, instead of extending `ans` as it goes.